# Changing Word document settings in batch

Tags: microsoft-word, batch

How can I apply some settings to all Word documents in a folder? (including subfolders)

For example now I want to change the background color of all my pre-existing Word documents to sepia (which is better for eye).

Comment: Refer to this: http://www.office-words.com/help/how.to.change.text.in.multiple.word.files.html may it will help you.

Comment: This program just deals with processing texts written inside Word, like finding and replacing. It can't add a new background color.

Answer (score 0):

This will take a complex macro.

See:

- [Document Batch Processes](http://www.gmayor.com/document_batch_processes.htm) by Word MVP Graham Mayor
- [Batch Process Folder Add-In](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/process_batch_folder_addin.html) by Greg Maxey

Comment: Maybe a good solution, but not for me. It takes me a year to apply. Too complex.

Comment: A year to apply? Download and use. Write a simple macro that changes your background color as your custom process.